# lextestpass.l:384: error: expected expression before ‘int’

Tags: c, compiler-construction, yacc, lex, flex-lexer

So I have this definition in a header file (actually the y.tab.h file):

```
  typedef enum yytokentype {
 TOKEN_UNKNOWN = 1000,
 TOKEN_ABBREV = 1001,
 TOKEN_AT = 1002,
 TOKEN_COMMA = 1003,
 TOKEN_COMMENT = 1004,
 TOKEN_ENTRY = 1005,
 TOKEN_EQUALS = 1006,
 TOKEN_FIELD = 1007,
 TOKEN_INCLUDE = 1008,
 TOKEN_INLINE = 1009,
 TOKEN_KEY = 1010,
 TOKEN_LBRACE = 1011,
 TOKEN_LITERAL = 1012,
 TOKEN_NEWLINE = 1013,
 TOKEN_PREAMBLE = 1014,
 TOKEN_RBRACE = 1015,
 TOKEN_SHARP = 1016,
 TOKEN_SPACE = 1017,
 TOKEN_STRING = 1018,
 TOKEN_VALUE = 1019
} token_t;
```

and this is a part of the function that I'm using:

```
static token_t out_token(token_t t)
{       
    int n;
int temp;

if (1)
{
temp = int(t);
temp = 1000-temp;
(void)printf("this is the value of the array : %d\n",temp);
(void)printf("%d\t%s\t", (int)t, type_name[temp]);
}
```

But it gives me the following error:

```
lextestpass.l:384: error: expected expression before ‘int’
```

Is it because of the typecasting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
int(t)
```

This is a C++ function-style cast.  The C-style cast uses parentheses around the typename:

```
(int)t
```

Comment: You sir, are brilliant. Small thing that I overlooked. *Embarrassing moments* Thank you.

Comment: No, I'm not brilliant. I'm just another fool who makes this sort of mistake all the time too.